# How to move button down under text in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am practicing my react skills and cant figure out how to get this button pictured below to be under the text.

This is my code:

```
 <div className="font-secondary text-xs md:text-base max-w-{100px} flex flex-row items-center gap-2 bg-white rounded-xl px-5 py-4 text-content-button font-bold hover:opacity-70 duration-300">
      {
        <Button href={LINKS.application} target="_self" external>
          Get Platinum access now!
        </Button>
      }
    </div>
```

[image: Button]

Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the styles to *flex column*. You're currently at *flex row*, which makes it parallel

Also you can remove the "{ }" since it is a children element of the div

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).